# C# - StateObject Class - Location

Tags: c#, class, system

This should hopefully be a simple one.

I am trying to learn about the Socket.BeginAccept Method from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bysfec7w.aspx

When creating the AcceptReceiveCallback method, you need to call an instance of the StateObject class, but intellisense on Visual Studio doesn't recognise this and the code doesn't compile.

I am using the System reference as well as several others.

Thankyou

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you don't need to pass a StateObject. It seems, that the example on that page is icomplete, because the StateObject is not defined. 
You can pass any object or even null. The BeginAccept method does not care. All it does is pass the value of that parameter to EndAccept method, where you can extract it from the AsyncState property of the asyncResult you can access from the EndAccept method.

This allows you to transport any information you might need in the EndAccept method from the BeginAccept method.

Comment: I think your right, they also don't define allDone or ReadCallback. I found the StateObject class at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx and imported it into my project and it seemed ok until I reached the last line, now I don't know what ReadCallBack is supposed to be. Thankyou for the advice on being able to pass any object or null, I'm going to try this now.

Comment: Just to add, I found the ReadCallBack method at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f(v=vs.71).aspx, although because C# is case sensitive you have to amend the casing on some of the variable/method names to get this to fit in with the class on the previous link, and the code in the original example.